# Cannot get text range of selection in a PowerPoint (Mac 2011) slide with AppleScript

Tags: fonts, applescript, powerpoint

I want to change Western and Asian font settings of selected text in a PowerPoint (2011 Mac) slide with AppleScript. Something like the following should work, according to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1894939?tstart=0). However, I can't even get **text range** of **selection**, let alone **name** of **font**.

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    tell active window
        set name of font of text range of selection to "Palatino"
        set east asian name of font of text range of selection to "YuMincho"
    end tell
end tell
```

Here is the result.

```
error "Can’t get text range of selection." number -1728 from «class TObj» of «class SelO»
```

In effect, the following issues the same error.

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    tell active window
        get text range of selection
    end tell
end tell
```

On the other hand the following simple VBA code works fine.

```
Sub HiraginoSansW2HelveticaNeueLight()
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font
        .Name = "Palatino"
        .NameFarEast = "YuMincho" 
    End With
End Sub
```

Essentially, the VBA does what I want, but it involves enabling Macro and saving in .pptm format rather than standard .pptx, etc. It's not as handy as AppleScript, which I can access from menu bar.

Could anyone help me get the AppleScrit work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some commands need to specify the window (even in a `tell active window` block)

Use `its` or `of it`, like this:

```
text range of selection of it
text range of its selection
```

Information of an AppleScript's term in Powerpoint: use `font name of font` instead of `name of font`

Comment: Now I tried it again and it worked! Both `set font name of font of text range of selection of it to "Arial"` and `set east asian name of font of text range of selection of it to "游明朝体"` worked as expected. Thanks a lot again!!!

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked well.

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    tell active window
        set font name of font of text range of selection of it to "Arial"
        set east asian name of font of text range of selection of it to "游明朝体"
    end tell
end tell
```